# Jquery double split string and wrap results separately

Tags: jquery, split, pseudo-class

I have a string $295.52
would like to split it and end up with the following:

```
  <span>$</span>295.<span>52</span>
```

I tried split the digits after the comma, successfully, but now I cant get a grip on the first character. Here is my code:

```
      $('.slprice').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().split('.');
            for (var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i++) {
                text[i] = '<span class="pricefix-' + i + '">' + text[i] + '</span>';
            }
            $(this).html(text.join(''));

       });
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having with it exactly? Are you having trouble extracting the first character? Have you tried using the substr() method? Example: `var Currency = text.substr(0,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regex for this, setting up groups to match the parts you'd like to split in to `span` elements. Something like this:

```
var $container = $('#foo');
var re = /(\$)(\d+\.)(\d+)/;
$('.slprice').each(function () {
    var matches = $(this).text().match(re);
    $(this).html('<span>' + matches[1] + '</span>' + matches[2] + '<span>' + matches[1] + '</span>');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwcsbsyo/)

Comment: would prefer to select the first character regardless of its value

Comment: Try this Regex: `/(.{1})(\d+\.)(\d+)/`

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatString(x)
{
y = x.split(".");
return "<span>"+y[0][0]+"</span>"+y[0].substr(1, y[0].length-1)+"<span>"+y[1]+"</span>";
}
```

And use it like

```
$('.slprice').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().split('.');
            $(this).html(formatString(text));

       });
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/70y2xh8u/)**

Comment: the $ symbol wont be dynamic in this case,

Comment: The curency sign `$`? Why do you mean by it won't be dynamic? Why you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: the currency may change per site / translation e.g £ /

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/32/)**

```
$('.slprice').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().split('.')
        var dollar_sign = text[0].substr(0, 1);
        var cents = text[1];
        var int = text[0].substr(1, 3);
        alert(dollar_sign);
        alert(cents);
        alert(int);
        //your other code
```

});

Comment: absolute answer, but not dynamic on the int. what if the price is $234454.90